# How to combine geom_violin & scale_fill_manual using transparent colors when yaxis is zoomed with coord_cartesian?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot violin plots with some transparency. However, my data has some long tail that I need to clip, but not discard the data for other geoms. When I perform the plot without the zooming in y-axis, everything runs smooth:

```
#load
library(ggplot2)
#sample data:
data<-data.frame(categories=c(rep("tomatoes", 1000), rep("grapes", 1000)),
                 subcategories=c(rep("fresh", 500), rep("rotten", 500), rep("fresh", 500), rep("rotten", 500)),
                 values=c(rnorm(n=1000, mean=10, sd=1), rnorm(n=1000, mean=5, sd=2)))
#my plot
ggplot(data = data,
        aes(x = categories,
            y = values,
            colour = subcategories,
            fill= subcategories)) +
     # limits to get all the data
     coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,15)) +
     geom_violin(position=position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
     # first value alpha is 80, second one is 255
     scale_fill_manual(values=c(rgb(255,0,0,80,max=255), rgb(255,0,0,255,max=255)))
```

[image: normal plot]

However, if I clip the data using "coord_cartesian", colors with alpha are removed completely:

```
   ggplot(data = data,
          aes(x = categories,
              y = values,
              colour = subcategories,
              fill= subcategories)) +
# Clipping 0 to 10
     coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,10)) +
     geom_violin(position=position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
     scale_fill_manual(values=c(rgb(255,0,0,80,max=255), rgb(255,0,0,255,max=255)))
```

[image: no transparent color]

Is this a ggplot2 bug or am I doing something wrong in here?

Comment: Sorry if I'm just understanding this wrong, is the issue that in the second graph, the tomatoes-> fresh is missing the filled in with that pinkish color? If so, when I run the code you have, for me the tomatoes-> fresh is still filled in pinkish.

Comment: @Silentdevildoll, same here, `ggplot2` v 3.3.5, R v 4.1.2.

Comment: Yes @Silentdevildoll, that is the issue. I'm using R v4.1.2 and updated ggplot2 to v3.3.6.9000 .

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Are you under windows?

Comment: This has been an issue on the windows device. Context: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4498

Comment: No, I am on a Mac.